# HTTP Post not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Clicking on the button shown in the index.html code gives me an error for the call "$http.post", (the web page alerts with 'Error!', so I can't save the new JSON file as I can't get past this call.

What am I doing wrong?

index.html

```
<td><input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" ng-click="doPost()" /></td>
```

app.js

```
...
$scope.doPost = function()
                        {
                            $http.post('/resource', {param1: 1, param2: 2}
                            ).success(function()
                                {
                                    alert("OK!");
                                })
                                .error(function()
                                {
                                    alert("Error!"); 
                                });
                        }
...
```

index.js (Server)

```
var fs = require('fs'); //File system module
server.post('/resource', function(request, response)
{
        //Every HTTP post to baseUrl/resource will end up here
        console.info('Updated myJSON.json');
        fs.writeFile('myJSON.json', request.body, function(err)
        {
            if(err)
            {
               console.error(err);
               return response.status(500).json(err); //Let the client know something went wrong
            }
              console.info('Updated myJSON.json');
              response.send(); //Let the client know everything's good.
        });
});
```

Comment: What's the error?  Is the request to the server what you expect it to be?  What is the server's response?

Comment: The error is that I get the alert: Error!.
There's no success the when I use HTTP.post
It should alert me with "OK!".

Comment: Yes, you're getting that alert because you wrote code to *show* that alert.  However, `"Error!"` is about as unhelpful as an error message gets.  So what's the *actual error* that your code is ignoring?  I suspect a function argument is being passed to that `.error()` callback, what's in that argument?  In the network tab of the browser's debugging tools, what is the actual response from the server?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. Anyway the Console on Chrome tells me "mywebsite.org/resource 404 (Not Found)".

Answer (score 1):

Use then function of $http like

```
$http.post('/resource', {param1: 1, param2: 2}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Comment: Tried this, stil nothing.

Comment: Then problem with your nodejs api, $http working like this, no problem with $http